# Grab text from a child element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navigation list as well as a separate headline and paragraph of text. Each list item has its own headline and text. When you hover over a nav item I want the main headline and text to switch.

**jsFiddle**

Currently my code displays ALL text. I only want to display the H1 & P text found within the class name `.spot_titles`: https://jsfiddle.net/d28zh777/

To illustrate what i'm trying to achieve:

[image]

When you hover over Acne or Oiliness or whatever the headline and text above should change to whatever item you are hovering over. This is the active state and what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

**jQuery**

```
// Get the original content
var main_url = $(".index__hero-image").css('background-image');
var main_title = $(".index__hero-image h1").text();
var main_text = $(".index__hero-image p").text();

$(".index__spot").hover(function () {
  var image_url = $(this).css('background-image');
  // These vars below are wrong I think. 
  var spottitle = $(this).text();
  var spottext = $(this).text();

  $(".index__hero-image").css('background-image', image_url);
  $(".index__hero-image h1").text(spottitle);
  $(".index__hero-image p").text(spottext);
},
function() {
  // Display original content when nothing hovered
  $(".index__hero-image").css('background-image', main_url);
  $(".index__hero-image h1").text(main_title);
  $(".index__hero-image p").text(main_text);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class=" index__text-block">
  <h1>Original headline</h1>
  <p>Original text block goes here</p>
</div>

<div class="solutions-bar">
<a href="acne.html" class="index__spot" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/700/700');">
<!-- Ignore next 3 lines / Create the icon in the link list -->
<img src="icon.png">
<h6 class="content-1">Acne</h6>
<h6 class="content-2">Shop Now</h6>

<!-- Use this text to replace that in index__text-block -->
<div class="spot_titles">
  <h1>Acne headline</h1>
  <p>
    Some text relating to acne
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this lines:

```
var spottitle = $(this).text();
var spottext = $(this).text();
```

to this:

```
var spottitle = $(this).find('.spot_titles h1').text();
var spottext = $(this).find('.spot_titles p').text();
```

This will get the `h1` inside of `.spot_titles` and the `p` inside `.spot_titles`.

You can read more about `find()` on [jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 1):

As you need to target the child element text, so use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) with valid selector

```
// These vars below are wrong I think.
var spottitle = $(this).find('.spot_titles h1').text();
var spottext = $(this).find('.spot_titles p').text();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Lo0ustmv/)